# Sum of equation's roots

Tags: quadratics

Find the sum of all real roots of all polynomials in the form of $y=x^2+px+122$, where $p$ can be all integers in the range $[-35,17]$

I could only do it via excel) Which is not mathematical proof..

Comment: What do you know about the sum of the roots of a polynomial ? When are the roots real ?

Comment: Did you find $377$ ?

Comment: Are you sure the solution is not simply zero? In fact your polynomial won't have any real root in this range of $p$. You must have $p^2 \geq 488$ to obtain real roots.

Comment: @PAM, $(-23)^2=529\gt488$.

Comment: Oh indeed! I just watched the upper bound!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. (1) Your polynomial has real roots iff $\frac{p^2}4 \ge 122$ or 
$|p| \ge \sqrt{488} \approx 22.1$

(2) Recall the *formula of Vieta*, that says that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of $x^2 + px + q$, then $p = -(x_1 +x_2)$ and $x_1x_2 = q$.

(3) Recall the Gauß' sum, $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac 12n(n+1)$.